# Is this is a sign of backing up of the downspout?

Tags: downspout

I suspect this shouldn't be happening. If there is an enclosed system in place, water should flow away from the foundation (in my case into a rain garden) and the damp ground is a sign of either blockage or improper connection of all the extensions?

[image]

Comment: Probably, given that the erosion of the mulch begins exactly at the location of the downspout.  But an easy way to tell would be to go look during a downpour.   You may even be able to see where the problem is though it's likely leaves, roots or collapse of the underground pipe.

Comment: It could be gutters too, or the downspout. Get them cleaned out, they are obviously over-topping on the deep end.